how to offset in the centre
So am in dire need. Is there any way I can offset a stroke path in the middle as a single line, not as a double line. I can produce that in single circle or square using offset but cant in letter. if offset is not the option in such case how can I do it? I need exactly in the middle, precisely in the middle. I dnt wanna do it manually. Any plugin? or anything? please guide me. :'(
Thank you.


You can rasterize and autotrace with centerline option. But realistically no automated tool in illustrator

am crying Joojaa. Thank you. I am in great danger, I will try that . :'( How can adobe forget about this and dsnt invent anythng who knows! I have researched a bit. pppl use blend for such case.. Thank you.

This is not a very easy problem to solve. , Sure for straight lines it is easy. But once you have curved lines its nolonger easy at all. You can do this in blender but only for M, you can get a good approximate of C too. You could do this in a mechanical cad though

yes. am trying sketchup. I stop learning 3ds max. now am paying. I shud nt. thank you so much for taking the time. Thank you.

Inkscape has a Hershey text extension, which is used to convert text to a single line path.  My answer here demonstrates it and where to find it.

@BillyKerr i dont like hershey texs because they are made from straight lines. I did however notice that true single line fonts are now available in illustrator again.

I dnt knw inkscape. @Billy :'( but thank you for guiding me. Thank you.
